# What is the maximum amount of file arguments I can pass to a command?

Tags: applescript, unix

If I do this in OS X, what is the maximum amount of files I can test?

Or is there a maximum length for this string?

```
do shell script "md5 -q 'path/to/file1.txt' 'path/to/file2.txt'"
```

Answer (score 1):

`getconf ARG_MAX`, or currently 262144 bytes.

If you get an argument list too long eror, try using find:

```
find . -type f -exec md5 -q {} \+
```

`-exec md5 {} \+` and `-print0 | xargs -0 md5` pass multiple arguments to md5, so they are usually faster than `-exec md5 {} \;`.

Answer (score 0):

This will find all of the visible files within the folder.

```
set myFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder)
set myData to (do shell script "find " & quoted form of myFolder & " \\! -name \".*\" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5 -q")
```

Comment: Thanks

I know nothing about unix. I have this old code which i copied somewhere and it needs tweaking (or tweaking of your code samples):
do shell script "find -x " & my_path & " -print0 | xargs -0 ls -d -F -P -l -T -a -e -i -o -p -q " & my_path user name "user" password "pin" with administrator privileges

Above code still don't get creation date & time.

My ultimate goal is log with information below & number of Finder label & md5 & Finder comment, something like this:
"46737077 drwxr-xr-x  2 Jonas   68 Oct  4 15:39:34 2012 /Users/Jonas/Desktop/test/test.txt 5 md5_here finder_comment_here"

Comment: @clueless5 Maybe it's better to ask a new question for this specific topic and include the goal of the command or what you want to accomplish as well. The comment section is not a good place for such things.